# SQL for MySQL - is there such a thing as a sub-key?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large database that supports a very large number of users. Each user has a unique key that auto-increments. Also, each user may have many common attributes that will relate to even more businesses. Rather than have a separate table of attributes that relate to the user key and the business key, which would end up being a HUGE 3 column table with way too many unique keys, I was thinking I could just embed attributes in the user table. That way the user key 47 would start it's attributes at 1,2,3, etc. and user key 48 would also start at 1,2,3, etc.

Is that possible? What would the schema look like?

Added this to clarify...

```
index | name 
47 | Joe
    sub-index key | attribute | business key
    1 | 123456 | 153
    2 | 987665 | 364
48 | Jill
    sub-index key | attribute | business key
    1 | ABCDEF| 293
    3 | 0-114-| 2394
```

In the above case, Jill did business with a 2nd company, but deleted her account. This way, the next index for the next relationship she adds will start with the index of 4, which is a requirement (immutable keys), however, the total list retrieved will only contain 2 items at this time (not 3 with one empty, which is also a requirement). I could do this easily with an interstitial table...

```
index | users | business | attribute
1 | 47 | 153 | 123456
2 | 48 | 293 | ABCDEF
3 | 47 | 364 | 987665
5 | 48 | 2394 | 0-114-
```

In this case, let's say there are 2 billion users, each with 10 to 20 accounts... The index for this interstitial table would become huge. Was thinking it would be nice to just have 10 to 20 indexes at the user level instead, but not sure if any such thing exists. I was thinking perhaps a separate table with a foreign key for the user, and some internal mechanism for a local key that can start at 1 for each foreign key, but I am pretty new to database work... just looking for some friendly ideas from the experts.

Was picturing something like this...

```
user-key | local key | business | attribute
47 | 1 | 153 | 123456
48 | 1 | 293 | ABCDEF
47 | 2 | 364 | 987665
48 | 3 | 2394 | 0-114-
```

Comment: I think this is hard to understand. Please edit your question and post your current schema and the one you plan. Also state whether the additional attributes for users are a fixed set (all users will have the same attributes (by type, name an meaning not (necessarily) by the values obviously)) or if it may vary.

Comment: I think you're asking about storing a collection of attributes in a single column of the user table. If that's what you mean, the answer is no, SQL doesn't support that. Each column must be a single scalar value (e.g. one number, one string, or one date).

Comment: If you're on MySql version 5.7.8+ or 8.x then you could store those attributes in a [JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) data type.

Comment: You can certainly use MySQL to mimic a key/value NoSQL storage (see [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)) but relational database engines are specifically designed to handle the scenario you fear that MySQl won't be able to handle. If you want document-oriented storage you use MongoDB, not MySQL ;-)

Comment: How many attributes do you have in mind? What about an attribute table with a column for each attribute, per user + BU ?

Comment: Updated my original question with some clarification.

Comment: There is a reason why it is considered good practice to normalise your database. What is "HUGE"? Just go for it.

Comment: So the problem you're essentially facing is to have "gaps" in the keys of the table, that tell if the use has deleted a row?

Comment: sticky bit, I won't have gaps in keys if I use the traditional approach of an interstitial table, but I may face the problem of scalability. However, if I try to avoid scale issues by coding a work-around and creating something like a json object in the user record, I would have to code for a bunch of stuff that comes native otherwise, including "gaps" in keys. I was hoping to learn something new - like the existence of a sub-key or something that comes with some native functionality I could leverage. I may just take trincot's advice and just use the interstitial page and go for it.

Comment: Hi. Just use the DBMS the way it ws intended. You have no reason not to except vague fears based on unfounded suspicions. Read a book on information modeling, the relational model & database design. Google many clear concise specific phrasings of your question/goal/problem/issue/proposal & read many answers. Google re smart database keys. Anyway this is too vague to answer. Also ...

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best".

Comment: Huge is so subjective. How many records are we talking?